# Multiple Components in HOC React

Tags: reactjs

I have already created High Order Component.I want to know in the same file only the one component should be called or i can call multiple ones and pass different datas.If yes will your give me an example.

Don't be too hard on me. I am practicing.

Here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

const WrapperComponent = (Component) => {
    const Container = (props) => {
        const [x, setX] = useState(5)
       
        return (
           <Component {...props} x={x} />
         )
    }
    return Container
}

export default WrapperComponent;
```

Comment: can you restructure your question? the sentence is quite hard to comprehend.

Comment: Why would you want to use HOC's while also using hooks? HOC's were primarily being used due to not easily being able to create common/shared component functionality. Hooks solve this restriction.

Comment: I want to use HOC's because i use the same datas  fetched from Back End in different components.